# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess needs regular DataAccess DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, data-access, fluent-migrator

I have an application that uses FluentMigrator and connects to an Oracle database to run its queries. Previously, it was utilizing Oracle.DataAccess to do this; but now I've been asked to make it use Oracle.**Managed**DataAccess; this is where I am having my issue.

When I run my app I get an error stating that it cannot find 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. I have altered all references of Oracle.DataAccess to Oracle.**Managed**DataAccess; however my application still seems to want this older dll. If I place that regular DataAccess dll back in the same folder as my app (along with the **Managed**DataAccess); it works.

**My Question:** Does Oracle.**Managed**DataAccess require me to also have the regular DataAccess dll in the project? It was my understanding that **Managed**DataAccess could do everything and not have any external dependencies.

Edit: Does a parameter passed into Migrate.exe imply a use of Oracle.DataAccess.dll? Possibly I am referring to it there and not recognizing it?

Comment: No, `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` does not require any `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`. Check your entire code carefully, somewhere you must have left a reference to Oracle.DataAccess.

Comment: Ok, thats what I thought. I searched my project and found the only references to the old dll, Oracle.DataAccess, are within the ManagedDataAccess dll itself. I'm assuming whatever those references are, they refer to something within the Managed dll itself? Because it should stand alone..

Answer (score 0):

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess should be all you need. Try running Agent Ransack on your solution directory and see if Oracle.DataAccess is still being referenced anywhere.

Comment: I figured out why even though I didn't reference it in my project, it still tried to find the old Oracle.DataAccess dll: I am using FluentMigrator, which has a paramter to specify database that you're using. I was resting on the assumption that 'Oracle' was what I wanted- however it turns out that there is also an 'OracleManaged' value for that parameter. I started using that and '"Lo' and behold!" it works.

Answer (score 0):

The answer wound up being that FluentMigrator, which I am using to call my project, uses parameters to specify database drivers. Previously, I was using the value "Oracle", because that was what type of DB I was connecting to.

However, when I changed to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll, I had assumed that that parameter in FluentMigrator did not need to change. ("I am still connecting to an Oracle database!") Turns out there is an "OracleManaged" value for that parameter.

When I changed parameter values, the application immediately stopped trying to find that old DLL. This explains why, even though I removed my references, the application still seemed set on using the old dll.